# Reference request: "Chapter 4. Binomial Coefficients"

Tags: reference-request

I believe [this chapter](https://kolosovpetro.github.io/pdf/CM4.pdf) is a part of some book on combinatorics. So what is that book?

Comment: looks like you pasted an invalid URL

Comment: I think it appears an error since url does not support https, I will reupload it somewhere else quickly

Comment: I would imagine... given the url... that this was posted by the teacher of the course labeled cs4205 at columbia.  You got the url somehow... perhaps by being enrolled in the class.  Why not *ask the teacher*?  For what it is worth, it does not appear to be formatted like I would expect a published book to be, so I would be more inclined to believe this is the teacher's personal written notes and teaching material on the subject.

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not enrolled to that great course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By digging a bit further, the website is not securely laid out and so we can access the files list [here](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/%7Ecs4205/files/)

We can then see [this course outline](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/%7Ecs4205/files/W4205PlanF09.pdf) where it tells us the name of the textbook is:

J. L. Gross, *Combinatorial Methods with Computer Applications*, 2008.

The author was also the teacher of the course at Columbia, so they had indeed been using their own personal text rather than a more polished and more common text.